# Unable to load CkoSshKey

Tags: chilkat

I've generated a sample key using `ssh-keygen` with no passphrase.

[image: Generate key]

It contains the following:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----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=
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I'm trying to access it via the following code:

```
#define kKeyPath            @"/Users/kylehankinson/.ssh/id_rsa"
#define kKeyPassword        @""

    CkoSshKey *key = [[CkoSshKey alloc] init];
    key.DebugLogFilePath = @"/tmp/chilkat.log";
    key.VerboseLogging = true;
    key.Password = kKeyPassword;
    NSString * keyString = [key LoadText: kKeyPath];
    if(!key.LastMethodSuccess)
    {
        NSLog(@"TEST: %@", key.LastErrorText);
        return;
    }

    success = [key FromOpenSshPrivateKey: keyString];
    if(!key.LastMethodSuccess || !success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", key.LastErrorText);
        return;
    }
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ChilkatLog:
  FromOpenSshPrivateKey(3ms):
    DllDate: Mar 19 2019
    ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.77
    UnlockPrefix: Anything for 30-day trial.
    Architecture: Little Endian; 64-bit
    Language: Cocoa Objective-C
    VerboseLogging: 1
    fromOpenSshPrivateKey(2ms):
      loadPem2(1ms):
        loadPem(1ms):
          itemType: OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY
          addPemItem(1ms):
            itemType: OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY
            This is an openssh-key-v1 key...
            loadOpenSshKeyV1(1ms):
              cipherName: none
              kdfName: none
              numKeys: 1
              szPubKey: 279
              szEncryptedPrivKeys: 984
              Unknown kdf name.
            --loadOpenSshKeyV1
            Failed to load private key...
          --addPemItem
          Failed to add PEM item.
          No more -----BEGIN's found.
        --loadPem
        Failed to load PEM
      --loadPem2
      Did you forget to set the Password property on this SshKey object prior to loading this private key?
    --fromOpenSshPrivateKey
    Failed.
  --FromOpenSshPrivateKey
```

Any ideas why I'm unable to open the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a new MacOSX Cocoa/Objective-C build that should fix the problem:

https://chilkatdownload.com/prerelease/chilkat-9.5.0-macosx-objc-1394.zip

PS> This download URL won't be valid forever..

Comment: Thanks Matt, that fixed the issue!